# mysql query not working for few variables passed from php script

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a php file and a database.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect('localhost','xxxx','xxxxx','joomla30');
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='EU'") or die (mysqli_error($con));

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
      $orders[] = array(
          'CountryCode' => $row['countrycode'],
          'CountryName' => $row['countryname'],
          'Select' => $row['Select']
          );
  }

  echo json_encode($orders);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I got the Database file from - http://www.geekality.net/2011/08/21/country-names-continent-names-and-iso-3166-codes-for-mysql/

The query - `$query = "SELECT * FROM countries ";` doesn't return anything.

The query - `$query = "SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='AS'";` works perfect.

whereas, `$query = "SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='EU'";` does't return anything.

Similarily 'NA','AF' did not work and others work perfect.

Note: All the above queries works well in phpmyadmin.

I dono the reason for this partial execution of this query.
Expecting a clear answer and correction for the same.

**Update:** 
Problem solved. Its a json problem. 
I encoded the connection into UTF-8 and its working now correctly.

Comment: "does not work" **HOW**? You get an error? No results? Wrong results?

Comment: Please explicit `doesn't work.`.

Comment: **DO NOT USE THE `mysql_` EXTENSION FOR NEW CODE AS IT IS NOW DEPRECATED**

Comment: Piling on here because this has to stop. Please, **DO NOT** use `mysql_query` in new applications. It's deprecated, dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) will help you avoid making mistakes like this.

Comment: @MarcB - I get no results.

Comment: @ethan - mysql_ changed to mysqli_

Comment: Change `mysqli_query(...);` to `mysqli_query(...) or die (mysqli_error($con));` so you can spot any errors...

Comment: @Shai Done.. No errors thrown.

Comment: ok. so SELECT * FROM countries where continent_code='EU' works in phpmyadmin, and not in php?

Comment: have you tried not putting the second parameter in your `while` ?

Comment: @Aris - Yes.. It works in phpmyadmin and not in php script

Comment: @user2690363 - Yes. No result.

Comment: @Aris - I get "resource(5) of type (mysql result)" while adding var dump

Comment: is the while loop ever entered? try var_dump($row) now

Comment: @Aris - The whole database is retrieved as dump..

While trying   print_r($row);, I get    Array ( [0] => AD [countrycode] => AD [1] => Andorra [countryname] => Andorra [2] => Principality of Andorra [full_name] => Principality of Andorra [3] => AND [iso3] => AND [4] => 020 [number] => 020 [5] => EU [continentcode] => EU [6] => 0 [Select] => 0 )

Comment: seems you get the data correct. maybe the issue is with the json_encode. do var_dump($orders) instead. Also define $orders=array() before the while loop

Comment: Ya tried @Aris.. Sample output for "EU": array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["CountryCode"]=> string(2) "AD" ["CountryName"]=> string(7) "Andorra" ["Select"]=> string(1) "0" } }
Hope so its Json encoding problem..

Comment: so  your array is filled ok now. even json_encode should print as expected. no reason to fail in this step.

Comment: So Json_encode is not working properly for all parameters.How to recover from that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `mysql_set_charset( 'utf8',$connect);`
Its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the native functions mysql_ ... should use PDO

```
Example:

//Connect to DB
$Conexion = new PDO('mysql:dbname=my_db;host=localhost', 'UserDB', 'PasswordDB');

//Prepare query
$Data = $Conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM countries");

//Execute query
$Data->execute();

//row Count
if($Data->rowCount()>=1) {
    $Array = $Data->fetchAll();

    //Process print data
    foreach ($Array AS $Key => $Value) {
        echo $Value['Column'];
    }
}
else {
    echo 'No Data';
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try removing trailing spaces (look after "countries"). ---> FROM countries ";
I found the same problem in an old PHP version.

Comment: Put SQL into a string.
Try again using the same query with mysqli and PDO (as suggested above) in the same script

Comment: Tried not working.. Database can be retrieved as dump..
Its Json encoding problem..